# setuptools, easy_install, and a custom pypi server

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, easy-install, pypi

I've got a custom pypi server running and am wondering how to point all references to https://pypi.python.org/ from there to my custom server?

I want to be able to cover cases of a user calling `pip` / `easy_install` of a package (so they don't have to remember to do `-i` or `-f`) as well as someone doing `python setup.py install` using setuptools with `install_requires` in the `setup.py`.

Is there some global config or setting I can do to get all these different methods to look at my local server? I imagine doing some network-proxy-type magic to route `http://pypi.python.org/` to my custom server would be one way to go but unfortunately that's not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The following configuration will disable the pypi repository index and make your index the only index used by `pip` and `easy_install`.  The setuptools `install` command is basically a shortcut to run the `easy_install` command on the current project.  So, that would work too.

```
# Add the following to ~/.pydistutils.cfg for easy_install
[easy_install]
index_url = http://localhost:8000/


# Add the following to ~/.pip/pip.conf for pip
[global]
index-url = http://localhost:8000/
```

Look at [easy_install's](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html#configuration-files) and [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/configuration.html#config-file)'s documentation for more information.

You could provide your users with a simple python script that creates these config files for them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change 2 files：

**For distutils**

- Configuration file: [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#location-and-names-of-config-files)

  - `~/.pydistutils.cfg` for linux,
  - `$HOME/pydistutils.cfg` for Windows
- Content:

  ```
  [easy_install]
  index_url = YOUR_URL
  ```

This concerns commands like `python setup.py install`.

**For pip**

- Configuration file: [doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file)

  - `~/.pip/pip.conf` for linux,
  - `$HOME/pip/pip.conf` for Windows
- Content:

  ```
  [global]
  index-url = YOUR_URL
  ```

This concerns `pip install mypackage` commands.