# Why does Pip disregard configured repository with nested dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, artifactory, rpy2, python-cffi

### Problem

Let us say I have a completely empty Python+Pip+R (pip 19.3.1) environment on a Linux machine and I want to install the package `rpy2` with pip. Since I am behind a corporate firewall I configure pip to use a private repository.

```
[global]
index-url = http://private.com/artifactory/api/pypi/PyPI/simple
trusted-host = private.com
```

Now I execute `pip install rpy2` and I will get back the following error:

```
Couldn't find index page for 'cffi'
 Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

So pip tries to resolve the nested dependency by looking and installing `cffi` from the official PyPi repository. It completely ignores the repo I have configured.

When I run `pip install cffi && pip install rpy2` one after another everything works as expected.

Here is the full error output:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8vuadu93/rpy2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8vuadu93/rpy2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-8vuadu93/rpy2/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-8vuadu93/rpy2/
Complete output (25 lines):
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'cffi' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for cffi>=1.13.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-8vuadu93/rpy2/setup.py", line 183, in <module>
    'rinterface_lib/R_API_eventloop.h']}
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 513, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 774, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1057, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1069, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 580, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 692, in easy_install
    raise DistutilsError(msg)
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cffi>=1.13.1')
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

### Question

**Is this a bug in Pip, a specific problem with rpy2 or am I missing something?**

### Updates

Running the following commands gives me the same error:

```
pip install rpy2 --no-index --find-links http://private.com/artifactory/api/pypi/PyPI/simple
pip install rpy2 --index-url http://private.com/artifactory/api/pypi/PyPI/simple
```

---

I used `-vvv` and it seems like the problem occurs somewhere inside of `setuptools`

### Solution

The package `rpy2` uses `setuptools` which again uses `easy_install.py`. It also works with an `index_url` variable. But it gets the value not from `pip.config` but `distutils.cfg`.

I identified all Python versions I have installed with `find / -name "distutils"`. Then I added the a `distutils.cfg` with the following content to each of these directories:

```
[easy_install]
index_url = blablabla
```

And now it works, I execute `pip install rpy2` and all missing requirements are installed in one go

Comment: What happens if you specify the config settings as command line arguments? Any difference? What happens if you also specify `--no-index`?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the private index in the requirements? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477117/pip-requirements-txt-with-alternative-index

Comment: Yeah I tried both with no positive outcome. I added the full Python stacktrace to my post

Comment: Did not investigate too far, but it might be because `cffi` is listed as `setup_requires` (it's also listed in `install_requires` of course). I would not be surprised if this dependency is downloaded outside the control of _pip_. Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15014180/11138259

Comment: Yes this was it! Thanks @sinoroc. Can you add an answer so I can mark the question as answered by you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it could be caused by the fact that `cffi` is listed as `setup_requires` in *rpy2*'s `setup.py`. Most likely because `cffi` is required to *build* the project itself before it can be *installed*. This kind of *build* dependencies are not handled by *pip* directly, so its `index-url` option has no effect.

The solution is to tell *setuptools* about the alternative index in a [*distutils* configuration file](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#distutils-configuration-files)

```
[easy_install]
index_url = https://my.index-mirror.com
```

References:

- ["Controlling setup_requires" in *pip*'s documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#controlling-setup-requires)
- [setuptools, easy_install, and a custom pypi server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15014180/11138259)
- [*distutils* configuration file](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#distutils-configuration-files)